# Where does ATXMEGA32E5 epad connects to?

Tags: avr, atmel, pinout

About the ATXMEGA32E5-MUR  (32-VFQFN Exposed Pad) Package:

[image: ATXMEGA32E5-MUR]

I do not know where the Central PAD connects to, since the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATxmega32E5-16E5-8E5-Data-Sheet-DS40002059A.pdf) does not mention it.

So I guess it is NC (No connect)? And it does not matter where I connect it to.

I even downloaded a library package hoping It will say something like "GND" but its labeled as "Epad"

[image: epad label]

Comment: It is very weird that the connection of the epad is not mentioned in the datasheet! My first assumption would be that the epad is connected to GND_1 and GND_2 (these will be shorted). To be 100% sure **measure it** using a multimeter. If you can't measure it (you didn't order the ICs yet) then I would assume the epad to be floating. Not connecting it should not be an issue. I mean, there's also a version that doesn't have an epad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**:
The MCU pieces came, I tested them unsing the multimeter and the pad in the center does not connect to anything. So it is an NC pad. I guess optionally one can connect it to GND.

(Guess its used as heatsink)